# Updating link on click jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to cycle through a list of links whenever a user clicks a "next" button, and brings them to a new page.

I'm having some issues finding a way to track at what item the user is in the list.

```
            var links = ["14232064", "13740143", "13738949", "14232077"];
            var linkIndex = 0;

            $(document).delegate(".arrows", "click", function(e) {
                 if(this.classList.contains("right")) {
                    linkIndex++;
                    console.log("click: " + linkIndex);

                }//end if
                else {
                    if(linkIndex == 0) {
                        linkIndex = 4;
                    }//end if
                    linkIndex--;
                     console.log("click: " + linkIndex);


                }//end else



            });//end click
            console.log("Outside click: " + linkIndex);
            $("a.arrows").attr("href",  "pdp.php?id="+links[linkIndex]);
```

I know at the moment this has some scoping issue...

Thank you

Comment: I think you probably need to check the right arrow click to make sure the index doesn't go too high. Other than that, is the only problem that the pdf link doesn't change? If so, try putting that line inside the click handler...

Comment: Thanks for the index catch, I forgot about that....however I need to have the attr change outside the click event because the link needs to update on dom load.